# My Leader's sudden change of heart ! Or why some plugins have the default leader changed?

Tags: vim

In short : my `<Leader>` key changes somewhere during startup. I have left it to be the default `\` but some of my plugins load with `<C-A>` instead.

I know that some plugins don't use `<Leader>` at all or use their own `<LocalLeader>` key or something similar (e.g. c.vim defaults to `\` even if you change `<Leader>` in the .vimrc. And this is in the plugin's documentation).

However my problem is with plugins that explicitly state that they use `<Leader>` and than end up mapped to `<C-A>something` rather than `\something`.

The plugins doing that are : Command-T, easymotion, screen, ShowMarks.

Plugins uneffected are bash-support, a.vim.

All my plugins are :

```
  1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim73/debian.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/synload.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syncolor.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim73/filetype.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim73/menu.vim
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/paste.vim
  9: /home/users/dslavchev/.vimrc
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim73/ftoff.vim
 11: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/vundle/autoload/vundle.vim
 12: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/vundle/autoload/vundle/config.vim
 13: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/Vim-R-plugin/ftdetect/r.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim73/indent.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/nosyntax.vim
 17: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/headlights/plugin/headlights.vim
 18: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/a.vim/plugin/a.vim
 19: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/bash-support.vim/plugin/bash-support.vim
 20: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/c.vim/plugin/c.vim
 21: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/errormarker.vim/plugin/errormarker.vim
 22: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/reload.vim/plugin/reload.vim
 23: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/screen.vim/plugin/screen.vim
 24: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/ShowMarks/plugin/showmarks.vim
 25: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/surround.vim/plugin/surround.vim
 26: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/taglist.vim/plugin/taglist.vim
 27: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/valgrind.vim/plugin/valgrind.vim
 28: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/YankRing.vim/plugin/yankring.vim
 29: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/NERD_tree-Project/plugin/NERD_tree_project.vim
 30: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/The-NERD-tree/plugin/NERD_tree.vim
 31: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/Conque-Shell/plugin/conque_term.vim
 32: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/python.vim/plugin/python_fn.vim
 33: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/vim-fugitive/plugin/fugitive.vim
 34: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/vim-easymotion/plugin/EasyMotion.vim
 35: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/vim-easymotion/autoload/EasyMotion.vim
 36: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/vim-rails/plugin/rails.vim
 37: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/L9/plugin/l9.vim
 38: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/L9/autoload/l9.vim
 39: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/FuzzyFinder/plugin/fuf.vim
 40: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/FuzzyFinder/autoload/fuf.vim
 41: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/FuzzyFinder/autoload/fuf/buffer.vim
 42: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/FuzzyFinder/autoload/fuf/file.vim
 43: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/FuzzyFinder/autoload/fuf/coveragefile.vim
 44: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/FuzzyFinder/autoload/fuf/dir.vim
 45: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/FuzzyFinder/autoload/fuf/bookmarkfile.vim
 46: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/FuzzyFinder/autoload/fuf/bookmarkdir.vim
 47: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/FuzzyFinder/autoload/fuf/tag.vim
 48: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/FuzzyFinder/autoload/fuf/buffertag.vim
 49: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/FuzzyFinder/autoload/fuf/taggedfile.vim
 50: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/FuzzyFinder/autoload/fuf/jumplist.vim
 51: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/FuzzyFinder/autoload/fuf/changelist.vim
 52: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/FuzzyFinder/autoload/fuf/quickfix.vim
 53: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/FuzzyFinder/autoload/fuf/line.vim
 54: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/FuzzyFinder/autoload/fuf/help.vim
 55: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/FuzzyFinder/autoload/fuf/givenfile.vim
 56: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/FuzzyFinder/autoload/fuf/givendir.vim
 57: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/FuzzyFinder/autoload/fuf/givencmd.vim
 58: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/FuzzyFinder/autoload/fuf/callbackfile.vim
 59: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/FuzzyFinder/autoload/fuf/callbackitem.vim
 60: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/command-t/plugin/command-t.vim
 61: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/clang-complete/plugin/clang_complete.vim
 62: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/clang/plugin/clang.vim
 63: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/better-snipmate-snippet/plugin/nerd_snippets.vim
 64: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/better-snipmate-snippet/plugin/snipMate.vim
 65: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/better-snipmate-snippet/plugin/support_functions.vim
 66: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/SuperTab-continued./plugin/supertab.vim
 67: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 68: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/gzip.vim
 69: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/matchparen.vim
 70: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 71: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 72: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/spellfile.vim
 73: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 74: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/tohtml.vim
 75: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 76: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 77: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/better-snipmate-snippet/after/plugin/snipMate.vim
 78: /usr/share/vim/gvimrc
 79: /home/users/dslavchev/.gvimrc
 80: /usr/share/vim/vim73/synmenu.vim
 81: /usr/share/vim/vim73/scripts.vim
 82: /usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/vim.vim
 83: /usr/share/vim/vim73/indent/vim.vim
 84: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/vim.vim
 85: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/lua.vim
 86: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/perl.vim
 87: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/ruby.vim
 88: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/python.vim
 89: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/The-NERD-tree/nerdtree_plugin/exec_menuitem.vim
 90: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/The-NERD-tree/nerdtree_plugin/fs_menu.vim
 91: /home/users/dslavchev/.vim/bundle/The-NERD-tree/syntax/nerdtree.vim
```

My .vimrc :

```
set nocompatible               " be iMproved
filetype off                   " required!

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()

" let Vundle manage Vundle
" required! 
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'

" My Bundles here:
"Bundle 'VimLite'
Bundle 'mbadran/headlights'
Bundle 'a.vim'
Bundle 'bash-support.vim'
Bundle 'c.vim'
Bundle 'errormarker.vim'
Bundle 'reload.vim'
Bundle 'screen.vim'
Bundle 'ShowMarks'
Bundle 'surround.vim'
Bundle 'taglist.vim'
Bundle 'valgrind.vim'
Bundle 'YankRing.vim'
Bundle 'NERD_tree-Project'
Bundle 'The-NERD-tree'
Bundle 'cflow-output-colorful'
Bundle 'Vim-R-plugin'
" Conque Term
Bundle 'Conque-Shell'
" Python
Bundle 'python.vim'
" original repos on github
Bundle 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-easymotion'
Bundle 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
Bundle 'tpope/vim-rails.git'
" vim-scripts repos
Bundle 'L9'
Bundle 'FuzzyFinder'
" non github repos
"Bundle 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
" ...
" Clang complete
Bundle 'clang-complete'
Bundle 'clang'

"snipmate
Bundle 'better-snipmate-snippet'

" SuperTab install
Bundle 'SuperTab-continued.'

filetype plugin indent on     " required! 

"Change Leader
"let mapleader=","
" Shows the leader
set showcmd
"This is to enable VimCCC
let g:VIMCCC_Enable = 1 
" Headlights debug
let g:headlights_debug_mode = 1
"This is for using autosyntax
syntax enable
let c_gnu = 1
let c_comment_strings = 1
let c_space_errors = 1
let urly_error = 1
" This is for omni completion
set ofu=syntaxcomplete#Complete
" This for replacing without changing clipboard
nnoremap S "_diwP
vnoremap S "_d"0P

"make buffers not resize
set noequalalways

" Highlights too long lines
if exists('+colorcolumn')
  set colorcolumn=80
else
  au BufWinEnter * let w:m2=matchadd('ErrorMsg', '\%>80v.\+', -1)
endif

" This is for numbering
set number

"This is for cflow
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.cflow setf cflow

"This is for tags
set tags+=tags
set tags+=tags;/
set tags+=~/.vim/tags/tags
set tags+=~/.vim/tags/opencv_tags
set tags+=~/Nuclear_Testing/tags
let Tlist_Auto_Open = 1

"This is for theasures and such
set thesaurus+=/home/users/dslavchev/.vim/thesaurus/mthes10/mthesaur.txt

"This is for mapping
let g:C_Ctrl_j = 'off'
let g:BASH_Ctrl_j = 'off'
nnoremap <C-h> <C-w>h 
nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j 
nnoremap <C-k> <C-w>k 
nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>l 
map <leader>, A,
inoremap <leader>, <C-o>A,
map <leader>; A;
inoremap <leader>; <C-o>A;

"This is for opening tabs
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set expandtab
set cindent


"This is for setting Makefiles with tabs not spaces
autocmd FileType make setlocal noexpandtab

"This is for errormarker
let &errorformat="%f:%l:%c: %t%*[^:]:%m,%f:%l: %t%*[^:]:%m," . &errorformat 
nmap <silent> <unique> \cx :ErrorAtCursor<CR>

"This is for showing marks
"command DoShowMarks

"This is for Valgrind
let g:valgrind_arguments='--num-callers=50'
let g:valgrind_use_horizontal_window=0

"this is for the path
set path+=.,inc,src,../inc,../src

"this is for spellchecks
set spell

"this is for easyreader
let g:EasyMotion_leader_key = '<Leader><Leader>'
```

Comment: It sounds like the questions should really be asked to the specific plugins when are not using <leader> as they say.

Comment: Are you sure that Command-T is affected? Judging by its code it doesn't seem to set `<leader>` to anything. Could you show us your .vimrc?

Comment: Also you can try `:verbose map <c-a>` and `:verbose map <leader>`. It will show you where your mappings containing `<C-a>` and `<leader>` are defined.

Comment: <Leader> works as some sort of macro. if you redefine it in one script all the following will change, but not the previous.

Comment: @romainl It shows me where the plugins define their shortcuts with <C-A> . Unfortunately this shows a lot of information but not what I need to locate the problem.

Comment: If your problem is that, somewhere, `<leader>` is remapped to `<C-a>` then `:verbose map <c-a>` will show you were all mappings involving `<C-a>` are done. It's up to you to follow those leads to solve your problem or not. Nobody here will take the time to look at the source code of all of your plugins. Did you `$ grep -r <C-a> ~/.vim`? That's the second thing I would do in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Finally.

Someone was changing the mapping in `screen.vim` plugin.

Simply grepping for mapleader in the .vim does the work.

```
" screen(1)-like mappings for buffers
" Ricardo Signes <rjbs-vim@public.manxome.org>

" there should contain a ^A between the quotes, below
" the next revision will have a nicer system for loading this plugin with a
" different meta/leader character
let mapleader = "" 

nnoremap <Leader><Space> :bnext<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>n       :bnext<CR>
nnoremap <Leader><C-n>   :bnext<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>p       :bprev<CR>
nnoremap <Leader><C-p>   :bprev<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>c       :new\|only<CR>
nnoremap <Leader><C-c>   :new\|onlyCR>
nnoremap <Leader>K       :bdel<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>S       :split<CR>
nnoremap <Leader><Tab>   :wincmd w<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>Q       :only<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>Q       :only<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>w       :ls<CR>
nnoremap <Leader><C-w>   :ls<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>a       :e #<CR>
nnoremap <Leader><C-a>   :e #<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>"       :BufExp<CR>
```

Comment: [Indeed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297767/my-leaders-sudden-change-of-heart-or-why-some-plugins-have-the-default-leader#comment13274125_10297767), `grep` to the rescue!